# TailwindCSS image is becoming bigger than parent div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a sidebar section called "suggested arrays" in a project, but no matter what I do, the image always breaks all the sizing settings and cannot be constrained. Whatever I do, I am faced with a picture that intends to disrupt my entire plan and order. I hope you can help me.

My CSS and TailwindCSS config.

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            grayish: '#e2e2e2',
            skyblue: '#466ce4',
            brand: '#5e17eb',
            slidergray: '#8d8d8d',
            grays: '#808080',
            linegray: '#eeeeee'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .scrollbar {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
        scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    }
    .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @layer utilities {
      .font-gothic {
        font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
      }
      html, body {
        @apply h-full;
      }
      html {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
        scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
      }
      html::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
      }
      body {
        @apply overflow-y-scroll;
      }
      .navbar {
        @apply w-full flex justify-center items-center h-16 border-b-[1px] border-grayish shadow fixed top-0 left-0 bg-white z-10;
      }
      .navbarContainer {
        @apply w-4/5 h-4/5 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-[4.88439142971vw];
      }
      .navbarContainer .logo {
        @apply h-full;
      }
      .navbarContainer .logo img {
        @apply h-full;
      }
      .navbarContainer .buttons {
        @apply font-sans flex justify-between items-center h-full gap-x-[3.79897111199vw];
      }
      .navbarContainer .buttons p {
        @apply cursor-pointer select-none;
      }
      .navbarContainer .buttons p:not([data-type="premium"]) {
        @apply hover:bg-slate-100/50;
      }
      .navbarContainer .buttons p[data-type="premium"] {
        @apply text-brand;
      }
      .navbarContainer .buttons p[data-status="diabled"] {
        @apply cursor-not-allowed opacity-50;
      }
      .banner {
        @apply mt-16 w-full aspect-[7/3] bg-black flex justify-center relative;
      }
      .banner img.top {
        @apply h-full object-cover z-[2];
      }
      .banner img.cover {
        @apply h-full w-full object-cover absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-[1] blur;
      }
      .content {
        @apply w-[calc(100%-200px)] h-full mt-[57.7443609023px] mx-auto;
      }
      .content .content_header {
        @apply w-full aspect-[1040/427​] gap-x-[60px] flex overflow-hidden max-h-[613px] items-center justify-between;
      }
      .content_header .slider {
        @apply w-[74.5%] aspect-[1817/1000] bg-blue-600 rounded-[14.4px] overflow-hidden relative;
      }
      .content_header .featured {
        @apply w-[21.6%] aspect-[45/86];
      }
      .content_header .slider img {
        @apply w-full h-full object-cover absolute top-0 left-0 transition-opacity duration-700 ease-linear;
      }
      .content_header .slider div {
        @apply bottom-2 absolute z-[5] flex justify-center h-[4.3px] mx-auto left-[50%];
      }
      .content_header .slider div div {
        @apply flex items-center gap-x-[17.3px] right-[50%];
      }
      .content_header .slider div div span {
        @apply h-[4.3px] aspect-[17/1] bg-slidergray rounded-full transition-colors duration-700 ease-linear cursor-pointer;
      }
      .content_header .slider div div span.current {
        @apply bg-brand;
      }
      .content_header .featured {
        @apply flex flex-col max-h-[613px] overflow-hidden
      }
      .content_header .featured > span {
        @apply mt-2 w-full text-2xl font-semibold flex items-center;
      }
      .content_header .featured .featureds {
        @apply grow grid grid-rows-5 items-start;
      }
      .content_header .featured .featureds > .featured_show {
        @apply h-full w-full flex items-end justify-center relative;
      }
      .content_header .featured .featureds > .featured_show > .details {
        @apply h-[85%] w-full bg-red-500;
      }
      .content_header .featured .featureds > .featured_show > .details > img {
        @apply object-cover;
      }
    }
  </style>
```

My HTML Code

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_header">
      <div class="slider" id="slider">
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
      <div class="featured">
        <span>
          <h1>Featured Shows</h1>
        </span>
        <div class="featureds">

          <!-- Problem in here -->
          <div class="featured_show">
            <div class="details">
              <img src="/src/thumbs/blahblah.jpg" class="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End of the Problemed section -->

          <div class="featured_show">
            <div class="details">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="featured_show">
            <div class="details">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="featured_show">
            <div class="details">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="featured_show">
            <div class="details">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: The output of the code]

[image: Expected result from the code]

[image: Size of the parent element includes of the image]

Comment: add `w-full h-full` to image also like `@apply object-cover w-full h-full`, see [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Jv4ywO3q37)